# How to check if classes share the same abstract class, marked with interface

Tags: c#

Imagine I have following structure:

```
    interface IAreExclusive
    {

    }

    abstract class Base
    {

    }

    abstract class AbstractBase : Base, IAreExclusive
    {

    }

    class A : AbstractBase
    {

    }

    class B : AbstractBase
    {

    }
```

I need to check, whether class **A** and class **B** share the same class, marked with **IAreExclusive** interface.
The check has to be as high performance as possible.

All following checks fail of course:

```
        typeof(A).IsEquivalentTo(typeof(B));
        typeof(A).IsSubclassOf(typeof(B));
        typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B));
```

Comment: The two classes have no relation with each other, they have a relation with `AbstractBase`. Why do you want that though? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Whatever the problem is, if you want high performance you need code that *doesn't* have to find relations between child classes

Comment: The classes don't have a `share` relation with AbstractBase either, they have an `is-a` relation. A *is* an AbstractBase, and so is B. That doesn't mean that A is B or vice versa.

Comment: Are you trying to use `IAreExclusive` as an attribute or marker interface perhaps?

Comment: Do you need to do this without knowing the type of base class/interface? If you know you're always checking for `IAreExclusive` can't you just do `if (A is IAreExclusive && B is IAreExclusive){}`

Comment: `The check has to be as high performance as possible.` Whatever approach you choose, **cache** the results in `ConcurrentDictionary` or similar - so if you need to ask for the results again, they are there ready to go...

Answer (score 0):

You can access `Type.BaseType` to check base types relations:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(A).BaseType != typeof(object) 
    && typeof(A).BaseType == typeof(B).BaseType); // true
Console.WriteLine(typeof(A)
    .BaseType.GetInterfaces()
    .Any(t => t == typeof(IAreExclusive))); // true
Console.WriteLine(typeof(IAreExclusive).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(A).BaseType)); // true
```

Comment: **BaseType** type property returns class **Base** and not the class **AbstractBase** with this **IAreExclusive** and that is the main issue I have.

Comment: @Wrymn can you please add reproducer? cause for me it [does not](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h7xbxd).

Comment: this is the link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hFxgOf
Notice I have updated the structure, to reflect the real issue. If you have any experience with Unity, I need to prevent components of same type, marked with **IDisallowMultipleComponent** to be added to same **GameObject**.

Comment: @Wrymn in this case you need to traverse `BaseType` something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ovmyqu). Also important note - it will work only if you have one `IDisallowMultipleComponent` in hierarchy. If you want to support multiple you can either use attributes or make `IDisallowMultipleComponent` generic and use it like: `IDisallowMultipleComponent<LayoutGroup>` . Both approaches will need code modification.

Comment: @Wrymn also i would highly recommend caching the search results for type somehow, cause in general reflection is expensive.